# How can I list all IPs in the connected network, through Terminal on CentOS 6?

Tags: networking, centos, ip

I was working on Centos and getting familiar with yum and I would like to know how to know which devices are connected to my network and see their respective IP and Mac address... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: For IPv6, ping the "all nodes" address: `ping6 -n2 ff02::1%eth0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nmap a lot of info can be regarded..

`nmap -A -v -v 192.1680.0/24` gives a lot of information, even SO in some cases

`nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` gives the MAC and IP adresses. Very Usefull too

`sudo nmap -PU 192.168.1.0/24` explains every ip

Answer (score 1):

To 'scan' the network you can:

- Try to ping the broadcast address. For IPv4 this is the one ending in all zeros. (e.g. for 192.168.0.0/24 that would be 192.168.0.255)
- For Iv6 see the comment from gravity: `ping6 -n2 ff02::1%eth0`.
- Or scan the network using [nmap](http://nmap.org). (text based)
- Or scan the network using zenmap. (a GUI front end to nmap)
- Or, if they **all** use DHCP, check the DHCPd logs. In many home networks this is trivially done by logging into the [wireless] router.

[Edit] This is not a complete list. But it should help you get started.